# Why does ''xargs bash -vc "$(declare -f {})"'' not work?

Tags: bash, shell, xargs, declare

**Bash 3.2.57** running on OSX.

1. Following displays the function definition as expected.

```bash
declare -f my_bash_function
```

2. Following works as well but only with **-v** flag.

```bash
bash -vc "$(declare -f my_bash_function)"
```

3. Following does not work as I would expect. It displays nothing.

```bash
echo "my_bash_function" | xargs -I{} bash -vc "$(declare -f {})"
```

4. However, if the placeholder is replaced with the function name, it works.

```bash
echo "my_bash_function" | xargs -I{} bash -vc "$(declare -f my_bash_function)"
```

5. Using single quotes, simply displays the command itself even if the function doesn't exit. Which means it isn't evaluating and/or executing it.

```bash
echo "my_bash_function" | xargs -I{} bash -vc "$(declare -f {})"
```

```
$(declare -f my_bash_function)
declare -f my_bash_function
```

Please explain why number (3) does not behave as expected?

Comment: Don't use `"$(declare ...)"`. Just use `"declare ..."`

Comment: You need `$(declare -f funcname)` to be run by your **local** shell, not the shell started by xargs. After all, the whole reason you're doing this is because the shell started by xargs doesn't know the function exists!

Comment: BTW, `xargs -I{} sh -c '...{}...'` is a source of massive security problems and should generally never be run by anyone. Normal expansions in shell follow different rules for expansion results that prevent those results from being parsed as syntax; when you have xargs just blindly substitute data into code, that data then can be used for injection attacks. The safe way to use `xargs sh` or `xargs bash` is to have xargs add arguments to the shell's argv, not substitute into code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you need `-v` in #2 is because you're using command substitution. So it executes `declare -f my_bash_function`, which outputs the function definition. This is then substituted into the `bash -c` argument, which makes the subshell execute the code that defines the function. When you add `-v` it prints the commands that it's executing, so you see the function definition.

The reason that #3 doesn't work is that the command substitution `$(declare -f {})` is being performed by the original shell, not the shell started by `xargs`. So it's looking for a function named `{}`, which doesn't exist.

It seems like you're trying to use `$(declare -f my_bash_function)` to export the function to the subshell. You can use `export -f my_bash_function` to put the function in the environment, and it will be exported automatically.

Comment: Thanks. So where is the output of the subshell directed to.
```function test {
echo "Hello"
}
```

When I run `bash -c test`, I do not see output on the parent shell. However `bash -c ls` behaves as expected.

Comment: Did you do `export -f test`? If you do that, `bash -c test` should work.

Comment: ```function testfn { echo "Hello"; }; export -f testfn; bash -c testfn``` prints `Hello`

Comment: @Hado99, remember, `test` is the name of a built-in command; it's expected not to have output (so when you don't export your function, you just are invoking the default test command with no arguments, and so get a silent failure with nothing printed)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Right. If you do the same experiment with my alternate function name `testfn` you get the expected "testfn: command not found" error if you don't export .

Comment: I see. Thanks. Yes exporting worked because it makes the function available to the sub-shell.

Comment: My original intention was to just print out the definitions of the list of functions.

e.g. 

```declare -F | grep -v "exclude some tuff" | xargs -I{} bash -cv "$(declare -f {})```

And I tried your suggestion above and that was exactly what I wanted. But because I did not **export**, it got derailed and went on to try command substition.

Comment: @Hado99, think about `readarray -t fns < <(declare -F | grep -v "exclude some stuff") && declare -f "${fns[@]}"` -- no xargs needed at all.

Comment: @Hado99, ...or `while read -r funcname; do declare -f "$funcname"; done < <(declare -F | grep -v "exclude some stuff")`, if you want to keep compatibility with bash 3.2; either way, that keeps it all inside one process [plus or minus some subshells, but being fork'd with no exec they inherit all parent state] so you don't need to start a separate copy of bash (requiring exporting your functions to make them available to that copy).

Answer (score 3):

Expansions in double-quoted strings are run by your local shell, **before** xargs is started. This means that values introduced by xargs cannot be used in those expansions, *because xargs hasn't yet been run!*

---

That is to say, when you run:

```
echo "my_bash_function" | xargs -I{} bash -vc "$(declare -f {})"
```

your shell *first* runs

`declare -f {}`

which (in bash 5.2.15) emits no output at all.

Consequently, it's replaced with:

```
echo "my_bash_function" | xargs -I{} bash -vc ''
```

...which, as one might expect, does nothing useful.